# Read certain line in text file and display the next

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and I need help. What I am trying to do is to find a certain line in a text file and display the next line in a textbox. With the first part (finding the line) I'm doing just fine but I am struggling with the second part which is displaying the line that is after the one I have found!

Here is the content of the test file that I am using:

[image: **SCREENSHOT OF THE TEXT FILE**]

lol

And this is what I have done so far:

```
    Using sReader As New StreamReader("filepath")

        While Not sReader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = sReader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains("123") Then
                TextBox1.Text = line
            End If
        End While

    End Using
```

Received result:

[image: **HERE IS A SCREENSHOT OF MY OUTPUT**]

Comment: If you want to display the next line, then the solution could be: `If sReader.EndOfStream = False Then Textbox1.Text = sReader.ReadLine()`

Comment: Thank for the answer muffi. So you mean that instead of having a while loop I should only have if statement ?

Comment: No, take the If - statement instead of `Textbox1.Text = line`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
While Not sReader.EndOfStream
    Dim line As String = sReader.ReadLine()
    If line.Contains("123") AndAlso Not sReader.EndOfStream Then
        Dim nextLine As String = sReader.ReadLine()
        TextBox1.Text = nextLine
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

With LINQ the complete code can be made much more readable:

```
Dim nextLineAfterMatch = File.ReadLines("filepath").
    SkipWhile(Function(line) Not line.Contains("123")).
    Skip(1).
    FirstOrDefault()

If nextLineAfterMatch IsNot Nothing Then TextBox1.Text = nextLineAfterMatch
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Tim !!! Exactly what I was looking for ! Take care mate :)