# Read part of text file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and I need help.

What I want to do is read lines from a text file that take place between two specific lines. Within these lines I have to look for a specific one and display the next line, if that makes any sense. The catch is that there are more than one pair of these marker lines that contain the exact lines that I need within them. I hope the explanation is clear enough for you guys! Is that possible?

[image: **HERE IS A SCREENSHOT OF THE TEXT FILE SHOWING THE PARTS AND THE MARKER LINES**]

I am looking for the line under the number 10 in the parts of the text file shown on the screenshot. Since there are a lot of 10s in that file I need to read it on parts in order to get the exact line needed.

The code below is what I have so far thanks to @TimSchmelter in my previous question [Read certain line in text file and display the next](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45011564/1115360). Which is actually the bit that looks for a specific line and displays the next one, but it reads all of the lines within that text file.

```
    Dim x1 As Decimal = File.ReadLines("filepath").
    SkipWhile(Function(line) Not line.Contains(" 10")).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()

    If x1 >= 0.0 Then TextBox1.Text = x1
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the multiple items? Sum them? Extract only the first one? Something else?

Comment: You have quoted me but if you'd told your real requirement i'd have never suggested that LINQ approach. But you stil haven't explained your own rules. The 10 changes but the `AcDbLine` seems to be the start of a block and the next `Line` seems to be the end. Is that correct? In that block you want to find the second line(so 0.0 in the first and 15.0 in the second part). Correct? If so, why don't you tell? If not, explain it carefully.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just need the line under the one containing number 10 if that makes any sense. The code above does that but it goes through all lines in the text file and when it finds the number 10 it displays the next line. what I need is to display that line under the number 10 in that specific part of the text file. Which in the part 1 case is 0.0

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes that is correct except that I do not need the second line only I need the lines under numbers 10, 20 and 11,22 but for the each of the number the code will take place in different 'subs'. These numbers are actually X and Y coordinates of line's start and end points and the lines under them contain the values. So basically 10=x1 and it's value is 0.0(that is the x coordinate of the starting point of the line) in the case of part one. I hope it is not too confusing.

Comment: @D.Ch: why you use such a way to store pairs? Why don't you store key-values in the same line? Also, there is no 22. Are these numbers fixed and will never change? Btw, better always post text nox images. How can we copy&paste it now?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes they are fixed and my bad for the 22 I meant 21 just trying to be fast with the responses. this file is not a .txt it is actually a .dxf which is other type of text file. So if it is going to make it clear here is the basic idea of what I intend to do: I am creating application with the use of which the user will choose that type of text file and the app will get the values of the coordinates for the start and the end points of each line and store them into the database. These coordinates will be used for specific calculations later on.

Comment: So that's why I need to extract this values reading it on parts because most of the text file's content is identical like the parts shown on the picture are. Does that make any sense or ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov bratle nqkakva ideq kak moje da stane tova ? Blagodarq predvaritelno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code was the best since it allowed you to have better control over what you read and whatnot, so I'm going to use that in my answer.

The LINQ approach will only give you the first instance of what you're looking for, therefore it is better to read though the whole file line-by-line.

First, a structure holding the coordinates of a line:

```
Public Structure Line
    Public Start As PointF 'Start coordinates.
    Public [End] As PointF 'End coordinates.

    Public Sub New(ByVal Start As PointF, ByVal [End] As PointF)
        Me.Start = Start
        Me.End = [End]
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal x1 As Single, ByVal y1 As Single, ByVal x2 As Single, ByVal y2 As Single)
        Me.New(New PointF(x1, y1), New PointF(x2, y2))
    End Sub
End Structure
```

We will use this structure so that we can return a list of all lines we've found.

This will read the file line-by-line and look for our wanted values:

> **EDIT:** I've updated the code to make it properly read the coordinates (i.e. it is no longer bound by the order: 10, 20, 11, 21).
>
> I have also made it only read coordinates located inside `AcDbLine/LINE` blocks.

```
Public Function ParseLines(ByVal File As String) As List(Of Line)
    'Create a list of Line structures.
    Dim Lines As New List(Of Line)

    'Create an array holding four items: the coordinates for 10, 20, 11 and 21.
    Dim CoordValues As Single() = New Single(4 - 1) {}

    'Declare a variable holding the current index in the array:
    'CoordIndex = 0 represents the first X-coordinate (10).
    'CoordIndex = 1 represents the first Y-coordinate (20).
    'CoordIndex = 2 represents the second X-coordinate (11).
    'CoordIndex = 3 represents the second Y-coordinate (21).
    Dim CoordIndex As Integer = 0

    'Declare a variable indicating whether we are currently inside an AcDbLine/LINE block.
    Dim InsideAcDbLine As Boolean = False

    Using sReader As New StreamReader(File) 'Open a StreamReader to our file.
        While Not sReader.EndOfStream 'Keep reading until we've reached the end of the file.
            Dim line As String = sReader.ReadLine() 'Read a line.

            'Check if we're inside a AcDbLine/LINE block and that we aren't at the end of the file.
            If InsideAcDbLine = True AndAlso Not sReader.EndOfStream Then

                'Determine if the current line contains 10, 20, 11 or 21.
                'Depending on what "line.Trim()" returns it will execute the code of the respective "Case".
                'Ex: If "line.Trim()" returns "20" it will execute the code of 'Case "20"', which is 'CoordIndex = 1'.

                Select Case line.Trim() 'Trim() removes leading or trailing space characters from the string (i.e. " 10" -> "10").
                    Case "10" : CoordIndex = 0 'We've reached "10", the following line is coordinate x1.
                    Case "20" : CoordIndex = 1 'We've reached "20", the following line is coordinate y1.
                    Case "11" : CoordIndex = 2 '[...] x2.
                    Case "21" : CoordIndex = 3 '[...] y2.
                    Case Else : Continue While
                        '   "Continue While" stops execution at this point and 
                        '   goes back to the beginning of the loop to: "Dim line As String = ...".
                        '
                        '   - If "line.Trim()" DOES NOT return 10, 20, 11 or 21 then we
                        '     just want to skip the rest of the code (in other words: ignore the current line).
                End Select

                'I used colons above for better readability as they can be used to replace line breaks.
                'For example the above SHOULD ACTUALLY be:
                '
                'Select Case line.Trim()
                '    Case "10"
                '        CoordIndex = 0
                '    Case "11"
                '        (and so on)
                '=========================================

                Dim nextLine As String = sReader.ReadLine() 'Read the next line.
                Dim Coordinate As Single 'Declare a variable for the current coordinate.

                'Try parsing the line into a single using
                'invariant culture settings (decimal points must be dots: '.').
                If Single.TryParse(nextLine.Trim(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Coordinate) = True Then
                    CoordValues(CoordIndex) = Coordinate 'Add the coordinate to the array.

                    If CoordIndex = CoordValues.Length - 1 Then 'Have we reached the end of the array?
                        InsideAcDbLine = False 'We've found all values we want. Do not look for any more in this block.

                        Lines.Add(New Line(CoordValues(0), CoordValues(1), CoordValues(2), CoordValues(3))) 'Create a new Line and set its coordinates to the values of 10, 20, 11 and 21.
                        Array.Clear(CoordValues, 0, CoordValues.Length) 'Set all the items in the array to zero.
                    End If
                End If

            End If

            'Check if we've reached an "AcDbLine" or "LINE" marker.
            'Used in order to determine whether we are inside a AcDbLine/LINE block.
            'If we aren't, then we shouldn't look for any coordinates.
            Select Case line.Trim()
                Case "AcDbLine" : InsideAcDbLine = True 'Start of an AcDbLine/LINE block.
                Case "LINE" : InsideAcDbLine = False 'End of an AcDbLine/LINE block.
            End Select
        End While
    End Using

    Return Lines 'Return our list of lines.
End Function
```

This code will only add a new line to the list once it has found four different coordinates, i.e. if it at the end only finds x1, y1 and x2 (but not y2) it will just ignore those values.

Here's how you can use it:

```
Dim Lines As List(Of Line) = ParseLines("filepath")

'Iterate through every parsed line.
For Each Line As Line In Lines
    'Print all parsed lines to console in the format of:
    'Line start: {X=x1, Y=y1}
    'Line end: {X=x2, Y=y2}

    Console.WriteLine("Line start: " & Line.Start.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Line end: " & Line.End.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

To get individual coordinates of a line you can do (assuming you're still using the loop above):

```
Dim StartX As Single = Line.Start.X
Dim StartY As Single = Line.Start.Y

Dim EndX As Single = Line.End.X
Dim EndY As Single = Line.End.Y
```

If you want to access individual lines without a loop you can do:

```
Dim Line As Line = Lines(0) '0 is the first found line, 1 is the second (and so on).
```

**Documentation:**

- [**`List(Of T)` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`PointF` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**How to: Declare a Structure (Visual Basic)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/how-to-declare-a-structure)
- [**Arrays in Visual Basic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)
- [**`Single` Data Type (Visual Basic)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type)
- [**`Single.TryParse()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`Select Case` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149051/discussion-on-answer-by-visual-vincent-read-part-of-text-file-using-vb-net).

Comment: @VisualVincent I am sorry to bother you again mate! I've played with the code and implemented the application a lot since you helped me, but now i need your help again i believe. I need to make sure that the values of the start or end pair (x,y) for a line do not appear more or less than twice in the list. Is this possible and could you help me to achieve that if it is? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @D.Ch : Sure. Just to make sure: A start-end pair may have the same coordinates, but not start-start nor end-end, right?

Comment: @VisualVincent you can. What i need is to check how many times the paired values of start and end (x,y) appear, so that i can use check later on with if statement probably wether a pair appears more or less than twice. the whole idea behind this is to make sure there are no separate lines. if that makes any sense. however I've decided to go for database way. mainly because i am familiar with sql server and it was easier for me to achieve the desired result. i create a table with one column and then count the occurrences of each pair. But I will be really happy to know how to do it in vb.net.

Comment: @D.Ch : Okay. I will try to compose something when I get the time. Currently I have a very busy schedule.

Comment: @VisualVincent No worries mate.Take care !

Comment: @D.Ch : So sorry for taking so long getting back to you. I've had lots to do both with updating one of my projects and writing some exams (I'm a student) as this semester is now drawing to an end. -- Anyway after working with this today I realized that I had misread/misunderstood your comment. If I know understand it correctly you wanted to check how many duplicates of a line there were, which made the solution rather simple (a one-liner infact, plus a few additions to the `Line` structure).

Comment: @D.Ch : In order for this to work you must update the `Line` structure's code to this: https://pastebin.com/QekUQm37 - then you can simply use the [**`LongCount()` extension**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548914(v=vs.110).aspx) to count the occurences of a specific line: https://pastebin.com/hMydbkYA _(in the code `Lines` is your `List(Of Line)`)_

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you very much for the help Vincent and sorry for the late response!

Comment: @D.Ch : No worries, glad I could help!